# Why doesn't PHP throw class not found error when using ::class?

Tags: php

When using the `SomeClass::class` syntax to get the FQN of the class, if the class doesn't exist it will just output `SomeClass` instead of throwing a fatal error.

```
echo SomeClass::class; // SomeClass

$class = new SomeClass(); // Fatal Error: Uncaught Error: Class 'SomeClass' not found

$const = SomeClass::SOME_CONST; // Fatal Error: Uncaught Error: Class 'SomeClass' not found
```

This seems undesirable to me. Why does this occur and is there a way to change this behaviour?

Comment: Did you import (include/require) php file before use it?

Comment: Ok, behavior is documented here http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class

Comment: @CamilleDell'Ava this question came about from a bug where I had forgot to import my class since I had disabled inspections on this file... oops !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `::class`-keyword is evaluated at compile time

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class)

> The class name resolution using `::class` is a compile time
>   transformation. That means at the time the class name string is
>   created no autoloading has happened yet. As a consequence, class names
>   are expanded even if the class does not exist. No error is issued in
>   that case.

That means, using `::class` doesn't call the autoloader and never throws an error. To call the autoloader, you have to create an instance of the class or use any function, which invokes the autoloader (i.e. `class_exists`)

You could come arround this by defining a simple test function, but I'm not sure, if that's a big benefit at all.

```
function class_or_fail($name) {
    if (class_exists($name)) {
        return $name;
    }
    throw new \Exception("Invalid class $name");
}

echo class_or_fail(SomeClass::class);
```

Comment: interesting.. so when it gets to the line with `::class` it's already a string so no error is thrown

Answer (score 0):

The class doesn't actually need to be defined in order to determine its FQN. It's simply a matter of using the namespace you're in, or matching any `use` statement in effect. If you want to determine if the class actually exists, there's a function for that -- [`class_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.class-exists.php).

Comment: Documented  here http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class

Comment: "The class name resolution using ::class is a compile time transformation. That means at the time the class name string is created no autoloading has happened yet. As a consequence, class names are expanded even if the class does not exist. No error is issued in that case."

Comment: Heh, I was going to say, think of it this way: "If I encounter the code `$x = new Foo();` where should I look for `Foo`?" The feature simply tells you how the namespace resolution would work.

Comment: 8-) So php resolves names that mabye not needed because that part of code is not execuded. wired.

Comment: Mh there is a function that is called `get_class(new Foo())` or `$x::class`. Hopefully php know witch way he goes. Becoming java or maybe becoming javascript....

Comment: It makes more sense if you think about it from an internals perspective -- if the class isn't defined yet and you want to try to autoload it, you need to know what namespace it would exist in.

Comment: I m a little infight with the term `fully qualified classname` at the definition. But, I will hammer that fact (feature) into my brain and leave it for now, thnx for reply. Did you know that this work `array_push($arr[],1);` ;-) have a nice day